# Thread Safety on my method

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety

Is this code considered thread safe even though multiple threads may be polling the directory for files on the webserver at once?

Thanks,
Mike

```
    //Get a testimonial
    virtualRoot = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;
    configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(virtualRoot);
    pathToNewsDirectory = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["VanHinoWeb.news.dir"].Value;
    fileListing = Directory.GetFiles(pathToNewsDirectory, "*xml");
    int index = generator.Next(0, fileListing.Length);

    //Put it into XML and get data into string array to return
    testimonialReader = new XmlTextReader(fileListing[index]);
    testimonialReader.ReadToFollowing("quote");
    testimonialData[0] = testimonialReader.ReadString();
    testimonialReader.ReadToFollowing("author");
    testimonialData[1] = testimonialReader.ReadString();
    testimonialReader.ReadToFollowing("authorTitle");
    testimonialData[2] = testimonialReader.ReadString();

    return testimonialData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the calls under the `Get a testimonial` comment should be thread safe. Accessing the hosting environment, app settings, and listing directory contents should be fine.

However, it's unclear where the `generator` object, `testimonialReader`, and `testimonialData` objects are created and whether they are shared across threads or not. If they are shared across threads, then the code is not thread safe.

Comment: I should also mention that all the objects used in this method are declared within the method. Therefor I thought that each thread will have its own stack of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As you are only reading files it looks that this is thread safe. Also you need to close the XmlTextReader (`testimonialReader`) after you are finished using it.